# Cómo cambiar la fuente en gráfico generado en r markdown pdf

Tags: r, fuentes, r-markdown, ggplot

necesito cambiar la fuente del título de un gráfico ggplot a calibri. Intenté usar la librería extrafont, pero al knitear me salen advertencias de tipo:  Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,:font width unknown for character 0x74. Y si bien el gráfico sí se genera, aparece sin texto en el título y ejes.

¿Existe alguna forma de solucionar esto, u otra forma de cambiar la fuente de un gráfico a calibri? gracias!

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-03-09'
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
extrafont::font_import()

{r pressure, echo=FALSE}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Example plot") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 11))
```

Comment: ¿En Windows o en Mc/Linux?

Comment: Se puede escribir `family = "sans"` para obtener la fuente por defecto de tu sistema. Sera parecido a Calibri

Answer (score 0):

para esto tienes que cargar primero las fuentes en tu dispositivo:

```
install. Packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win", quiet = TRUE)
font_import()
```

Cargar las fuentes puede tardar unos minutos. Después ya corres el código.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Example plot") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "calibri"))
```